# File upload in admin cause 400 Error

Tags: django

Using django 1.7 and python3.2 I've been working on a model. The picture field keep sending me a 400 Error when i'm trying to upload a JPG picture <strike>but works perfectly well when using a PNG.</strike> **It is just randomly accepting some pictures**

I've removed to 'upload_to' parameter since I tough it was what caused the error. Apparently not. Is it worth creating an issue or am I missing something ?

UPDATE : PNG files can create the error as well. Converted the picture with photoshop and I still got the error. After a while I tried to reproduce the error to get a traceback and it worked perfectly fine... I'll post the exact error I got as soon as it happens again

```
class Release(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    label = models.ForeignKey('Label')
    author = models.ForeignKey('Artist')
    picture = models.FileField(blank=True, null=True)
    public = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

My terminal prints :

```
[04/Dec/2014 09:46:20] code 400, message Bad request syntax ('\x0b\x97\x98tÚd\x7fÒ\x9a8ê\x99G\\åb\x8f776_¾z5\x9b\x7f¾à¶¶u>}öâ¯¿9ÀÀ)7_ÿÇß\x9fø*±ã\x7füí7\x8d\x9a\x9eÒWÉ"I7å=\x06²5Ôû«÷\r«\x95i©\x9aðw²ÐDºfªC\x87P¬7R\x891\x9d%¢\x11)}dQ\x02×æå\x01Ôññ»££ã²\x888ÿàëWÉú¹2P\x04¿«-a\x10HÀ{ëPðÕ{)Ãl+þþjÏ71ç¦ø¯\x87;\x9bd3á\rªý\x03k\x07Ûô\x8cgÏ÷ÿïÿùï¯÷önÚÅsÃZ8\x95®´¦æ\x9fþZ×\x80.Ä\x838\x84ìJ\'Ap\x8a$b:ãòê4ÕÉ\x1e\x90\x03\x83¼1mC; \x86ÚÐ^¾÷\x99')
[04/Dec/2014 09:46:20] "ªýkÛôgÏ÷ÿïÿùï¯÷önÚÅsÃZ8®´¦æþZ×.Ä8ìJ'Ap$b:ãòê4ÕÉ¼1mC; ÚÐ^¾÷" 400 -;
```

And I either receive a "not available page" or the same error. No traceback and no log in my logging file.

My settings.py:

```
FILE_UPLOAD_PERMISSIONS = 0o644
MEDIA_ROOT = 'upload/'
MEDIA_URL = ''
```

I also changed my model to have :

```
picture = models.ImageField(blank=True, null=True)
```

But this doesn't help at all...

WEIRD UPDATE :

Cannot reproduce the bug in front of a Friend. Now wonder what gonna do with that bounty, Mysteries of Django EP 1 in 3 year of web dev in Django.

WEIRD UPDATE 2 :

Removed my BDD and re-synced : problem appeared again...

Info edito : IT'S ALL IN THE DJANGO ADMIN, NO CUSTOM HTML, NO CUSTOM CODE EXCEPT THE ONE I POSTED HERE

Screenshot of the error... https://i.stack.imgur.com/oAcL1.jpg

Comment: Are you mixing mixing http and https requests?

Comment: Nop, all in local. The same error is thrown when I try to upload a file with a filename already taken. Appears it's quite no properly handled from Django side. Think I'll try to open an issue concerning that.

Comment: Could you post your html code?

Comment: No HTML code, it' all in the non customized admin.

Comment: Remember to use `unicode` to all strings. If you have special characters like `àèãòê4ÕÉ¼1m` you should do `u"àèãòê4ÕÉ¼1m"`

Answer (score 1):

*Mabye* the failing images have filenames that contain non-ascii characters?

Change `__str__`  to `__unicode__` (edited for markdown)

Comment: Oh didn't think about that it looks plausible, where should I change that ?

Comment: In your own snippet you have `def __str__` (my underscores got eaten by markdown)

Comment: Oh tried that but it shouldn't actually affect the picture since it's only a way to represent the model. I tried it anyway and still got the problem :(

Comment: Remove any unicode character on your image file name and see if it uploads ok

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

to

```
def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title
```